# Свойство object-fit + transition

Tags: html, css

Верстаю блоки для изображений с разным размером.

```css
.product img {
  transition: .3s ease;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.product img:hover {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <img src="someimg.jpg">
</div>
```

Хочу сделать чтобы при наведении изображение помещалось в блок плавно.
Проблемма в том что object-fit и transition не работают вместе.
Может кто-сталкивался с такой проблеммой...
Подскажите пожалуйста, как ее можно решить попроще ( без js и танцев з бубном)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object-fit это не то свойство которое может быть [анимировано](https://webref.ru/css/animated_properties)
Твоя задача решается через свойство `transform: scale(1);` `.product img:hover{transform: scale(1.5);}` если тебе пренципиально что б изображение вписывалось в блок, можешь диву оббертке задать `overflow:hidden; position:relative;`